# JQuery returning number of children more than what exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the problem I'm having is that my jQuery code is somehow detecting more children than there exist in for an element. I'll do my best to explain what I'm trying to do.
I have a table in the following format:

```
 <table>
                        <!-- BEGIN SECTION: General Attributes -->
                        <tbody class="tableHeadings">
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">
                                    <hr />
                                    <h3 class="tableSectionHeader">General Characteristics</h3>
                                    <hr />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="venue">Venue</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="pubYear">Publication Year</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="abstract">Abstract</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="author">Authors</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="url">URL</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="researchQuestions">Research Question</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="experienceDescription">Experience Description</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="whatMeasured">What Measured</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="howMeasured">How Measured</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="articleEvaluationTool">Evaluation Tool Used</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="reportType">Report Type</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="studyDesign">Study Design</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="researchApproach">Research Approach</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>


<tbody class="tableHeadings durationHeader">
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">
                                    <hr />
                                    <h3 class="tableSectionHeader">Duration Information</h3>
                                    <hr />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="years">Total Years</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="semesters">Total Semesters</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="months">Total Months</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="weeks">Total Weeks</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="days">Total Days</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="hours">Total Hours</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="minutes">Total Minutes</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="daysPerWeek">Days Per Week</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="hoursPerDay">Hours Per Day</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="library-card-header" id="minutesPerDay">Minutes Per Day</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>

</table>
```

What I'm doing is using JS to populate the td's with the relative information if it exists in the database. If it doesn't I'm removing the tr altogether so it doesn't show up at all on the page (rather than showing up with just heading and no information). The populating part is working seamlessly. However, removing the sections which have no data is not working for only the section 'duration header'.

The JS code I wrote to achieve this is:

```
jQuery("th").each(function(item){

    var idAttribute = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var result = data[idAttribute];
    if(result == undefined || result.length == 0) {

        // Remove any element that has no data. Skip over the section headers.
        if (idAttribute !== undefined)
            jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        return;
    }

    // Remove any duration information with a zero value.
    if (isDurationAttr(idAttribute))
    {
        if (result === 0)
        {
            jQuery(this).parent().remove();
            return;
        }

    }

    jQuery('.tableHeadings').each(function() {
    //  console.log(jQuery(this).children().length);
        if (jQuery(this).children().length == 1) {
            jQuery(this).remove();  
            return;
        }
    });
    var tree = jQuery(".durationHeader").map(function(){
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).get().join(", ");

    console.log(tree);
});
```

While debugging this, I tried to print out the number of children in the last part and then the html that is in the durationHeader section.

the method

```
    jQuery('.tableHeadings').each(function() {
    //  console.log(jQuery(this).children().length);
        if (jQuery(this).children().length == 1) {
            jQuery(this).remove();  
            return;
        }
    });
```

should essentially get rid of the durationHeader section. However, when I print out the html, its showing all the elements. For some very weird reason, this is not happening for the first tbody, which is also a class tableHeadings. When I printed out the children in durationHeader, it says that the element has 11 children. It should have only 1, which is the heading of that section.

Can someone please look into this and tell me what is going on? I've been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: Could you check your JavaScript code, you have some missing `}` and `)`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Missed the closing braces. Fixed it.

Comment: @Ivan I'm getting it as a JSON response on the page. For simplicity purposes I didn't share that because the data is being fetched correctly I made sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely your first `tbody` has 14 `tr` elements while the second `tbody` has 11. The code is working fine. Tell me if that's not what you were looking for.

**Edit:** I think I know what you're not understanding: `jQuery('.tableHeadings')` contains two elements, the two elements with class name `.tableHeadings`. So when you apply `each` you're not looping through each child of the table portion, you're looping through each table portion (here there are two). Therefore accessing `children` will get you the `tr` elements instead of the child of the first `tr`: `th`.

```js
jQuery('.tableHeadings').each(function() {
  console.log(jQuery(this).children().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <!-- BEGIN SECTION: General Attributes -->
  <tbody class="tableHeadings">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <hr />
        <h3 class="tableSectionHeader">General Characteristics</h3>
        <hr />
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="venue">Venue</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="pubYear">Publication Year</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="abstract">Abstract</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="author">Authors</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="url">URL</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="researchQuestions">Research Question</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="experienceDescription">Experience Description</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="whatMeasured">What Measured</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="howMeasured">How Measured</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="articleEvaluationTool">Evaluation Tool Used</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="reportType">Report Type</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="studyDesign">Study Design</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="researchApproach">Research Approach</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>


  <tbody class="tableHeadings durationHeader">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <hr />
        <h3 class="tableSectionHeader">Duration Information</h3>
        <hr />
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="years">Total Years</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="semesters">Total Semesters</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="months">Total Months</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="weeks">Total Weeks</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="days">Total Days</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="hours">Total Hours</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="minutes">Total Minutes</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="daysPerWeek">Days Per Week</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="hoursPerDay">Hours Per Day</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="library-card-header" id="minutesPerDay">Minutes Per Day</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I think I do understand that. I do not want to or need to reach the th. If I just remove the tr, the th gets removed automatically since its a child. 
The code works fine for the first tbody. It removes all the trs which do not have any data in it. It does that for the second tbody (durationHeader) so when you look at the html, you don't see any of the trs. However, when I print using console.log(tree), its showing me all the trs there in the console. This is the problem I'm having since its preventing me from removing this tbody dynamically. This does not happen for the first tbody.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce the problem without having the necessary data/functions you are calling in your snippet. You may want to rephrase your question and had a minimal example so I can try to help you out.